# .css effect is not being applied after ajax response

Tags: jquery, css

Im trying to apply a jquery .css effect after an ajax success response. I suppose that this doesnt work because Im getting the height from a recently generated element and then applying it to another recently generated element. I'm trying to move the .opts div to bottom, based in the height of the .col-4 div, which is dynamic.

Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/Pancuatico/pen/abpOeZy

When you open the pen, you can apply this code in the console: `$(".opts").css("margin-top",$(".col-4").height());` and you will see that it works perfectly but, what is the right way to make this work after that ajax success response?

**Edit**

I'll put my js code here, so you can see where is my mistake.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadImgs();
});

function loadImgs(){
    $.post("anurl.php",function(data){

        //Some process with the data here
        //...

        var out = "<div class='col-4'><img src='imgpathalt' alt='imgpath'></div>";
        out += "<div class='col-2'>";
            out += "<img src='imgpath2' alt='imgpath2alt'>";
            out += "<div class='opts'>";
                out += "<button>add</button>";
                out += "<button>rm</button>";
            out += "</div>";
        out += "</div>";

        $(".row").html(out);
        var col4Height = $(".col-4").height();
        $(".opts").css("margin-top",col4Height); //this does not work
    });
}
```

Comment: console.log(col4Height)

Comment: @flakerimi I did it and if it is inside the success response, it prints "24". If you run `$(".col-4").height()` from the console, it shows the right height, which is what Im trying to use to bring that .opts div to bottom.

Comment: `$(".opts").css("margin-top",col4Height+"px")`. `24` without a unit is an invalid property value for `margin-top`.

Comment: @connexo I did what you are suggesting but it still doesn't work because ´colHeight´ is taking a wrong height there. if you put this: `$(".col-4").height()` in the console, you will see that the .col-4 is greather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, when you are adding the `margin-top` of that elements, **the images are still loading up**. So the height of `.col-4` is only about the size of the buttons at that moment.
You have to wait till the images are loaded, then update the margin equal to the height of `.col-4`.

A Better way would be to create the elements dynamically, instead of putting as html in a string. That way you can bind the load event on that image with-

```
myImage.load(imgLoaded);
```

and to update the margin after image is loaded-

```
function imgLoaded() {
$(".opts").css("margin-top", $(".col-4").height();); 
}
```

However, you can achieve your result in your code with html `onload` attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadImgs();
});

function loadImgs(){
    $.post("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js",function(data){

        //...
        //Some process with the data here
        //Im just using that url for testing purposes
        //...

        var out = "<div class='col-4'><img src='https://cutt.ly/IxR1RrQ' alt='https://bit .ly/3tI1rWa' onload='imgLoaded()'></div>";
        out += "<div class='col-2'>";
            out += "<img src='https://cutt.ly/IxR1RrQ' alt='https://bit .ly/3tI1rWa'>";
            out += "<div class='opts'>";
                out += "<button>add</button>";
                out += "<button>rm</button>";
            out += "</div>";
        out += "</div>";

        $(".row").html(out);

    });
}

function imgLoaded() {
    $(".opts").css("margin-top", $(".col-4").height();); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working

https://codepen.io/flakerimi/pen/ZELbYoK

I added more css params and they show up.

```
        var col4Height = $(".col-4").height();
        $(".opts").css("padding",'10px');  

        $(".opts").css("background",'green');  
        $(".opts").css("top",col4Height);
```

Also use `$(".opts").css("top",col4Height);`   since its position absolute

---

I would do it differently tho.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    doWork();
});

async function loadImages(){}

async function doWork(){
    await loadImages();

    //do some other stuff after loadImages is finished like
    var col4Height = $(".col-4").height();
    $(".opts").css("padding",'10px');  

}
```

CHECK THIS

```
$(document).ready(async function() {
  await loadImgs();
 // When we begin, assume no images are loaded.
  var imagesLoaded = 0
  // Count the total number of images on the page when the page has loaded.
  var totalImages = $("img").length

  // After an image is loaded, add to the count, and if that count equals the
  // total number of images, fire the allImagesLoaded() function.
  $("img").on("load", function (event) {
    imagesLoaded++
    if (imagesLoaded == totalImages) {
      allImagesLoaded()
    }
  })

  function allImagesLoaded() {
    console.log("ALL IMAGES LOADED");
     change();
  }
  });

async function change(){
 
    if($(".col-4").height() != 0) {
   var col4Height = $(".col-4").height();
      console.log(col4Height);
        $(".opts").css("padding",'10px'); //this does not work
   
        $(".opts").css("background",'green'); //this does not work
        $(".opts").css("margin-top",col4Height); //this does not work
    }
};
async function loadImgs(){
   await $.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //...
        //Some process with the data here
        //Im just using that url for testing purposes
        //...
...

     
 
    });      
  var col4Height = $(".col-4").height();
  console.log(col4Height);

}
```

Comment: add    $(".opts").css("top",col4Height *4 );   to see difference

Comment: I'm trying to avoid setting the height arbitrarily. The .col-4 height is dynamic so I can't use .colHeight*10 or *4 or * whatever. Also check the .col-4 height in the console, you will see that it is not 24 after that ajax success response.

Comment: I have updated my pen. This is not working because it loads before Image loads, and thats why is giving 24. I made an update on my pen